# Set Default for Radio Button in C++

Tags: visual-c++

I have 2 Radio Buttons in a MFC application designed with C++, I would like to set the focus on the second Radio button when the app is launched. Does anyone know how I should do this? I am using VS2005. Thanks.

Comment: I usually programmatically select the radio in the WM_CREATE but I'm not sure if there's a better way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
BOOL myDlg::OnInitDialog()
{
        CDialog::OnInitDialog();
        pButton2 = (CButton*)this->GetDlgItem(IDC_RADIO2);
        pButton2->SetFocus();
        pButton2->SetCheck(true); 
}
```